# role of temp folder in war file deployment in tomcat 6

Tags: tomcat, deployment, war, temp

When i deploy spring web application to tomcat 6 with maven,a war file and an unpacked version of this war file is created under webapps folder,at the same time an unpacked version of war file named 0-app_name is also generated under temp folder of tomcat.Can someone explain the lifecycle of the deployed war file? Why the temp folder is used while the same war and unpacked version of it exists under webapps folder.

Answer (score 3):

`antiResourceLocking` and `antiJARLocking` use it. ([Tomcat doc, The Context Container](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation))

[Tomcat FAQ: I want to redeploy web applications, how do I prevent resources from getting locked?](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Windows#Q5)

> There is another lock prevention mechanism in Tomcat 5.5
>   (antiResourceLocking attribute), which will cause the web application
>   files to be copied to the temp folder and run from this location. This
>   has a larger impact on web application startup times, but obviously
>   prevents locking on all resources of the web application. This also
>   allows more flexible management operations as none of the web
>   application resources will be locked, even while the web application
>   is running (as a special note, when making changes to JSPs without
>   reloading the application, the changes have to be duplicated to the
>   path where the web application resources have been copied in the temp
>   folder).

Comment: when  antiResourceLocking attribute in context.xml of tomcat 6.0.29,it's worked for me.Thanks.

Comment: @yesildal IF you are satisfied with an answer, you can accept it by clicking the green pipe on the left side. It rewards the answering person.